# Offset Droppable using Jquery

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

[image]

My droppable area seems to be offset by the width of the draggable item.  This means when I try to add a draggable to a droppable, it becomes active when it's not actually on top of the item (in my image, the Add New Step is my draggable div, and New Step is the droppable).  How can I set an offset to the droppable object to account for the width of the draggable?

This is what I've tried (which doesn't work):

```
 $('.newStep').draggable();
 $('.newStep').draggable('enable');

  $('.stepNode').not('.newStep').droppable({
       create: function(event, ui){
       var off = $(this).offset();
       console.log("off.left: " + off.left);
       off.left += ui.draggable.width()/2;
       ui.draggable.offset(off);
     },
     disabled: false
   });
```

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/jdxA8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$( ".drag" ).draggable();
$( ".drop" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    var off = $( this ).offset();
    off.top += 5;
    off.left += 5;
    ui.draggable.offset( off );
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/iqunod/1/edit

Comment: Thanks; I tried that, but it didn't seem to change the offset at all (see above).  I tried both using the create and drop events, but neither worked.  Also, the log message I put in doesn't ever show.

Comment: I would need you to post your current issue on jsfiddle or jsbin so I can try to fix it.

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure why you example doesn't work.  I tried to get it to work but there is something about it that won't work.  Nevertheless, I created an example doing what you are trying to do: one draggable object, multiple droppable objects.  See here, it's the best I can do since I don't have time http://jsbin.com/EJuCiTu/1/edit